# Why am I getting this AttributeError for a method in my class?

Tags: python, class, methods

Here is my code:

```
class MinerNotFullAction:
   def __init__(self, entity, image_store):
      self.entity = entity
      self.image_store = image_store

   def miner_to_ore(self, world, ore):
      entity_pt = MinerNotFull.get_position(self.entity)
      if not ore:
         return ([entity_pt], False)
      ore_pt = MinerNotFull.get_position(ore)
      if adjacent(entity_pt, ore_pt):
         MinerNotFull.set_resource_count(self.entity,
            1 + MinerNotFull.get_resource_count(self.entity))
         remove_entity(world, ore)
         return ([ore_pt], True)
      else:
         new_pt = next_position(world, entity_pt, ore_pt)
         return (worldmodel.move_entity(world, entity, new_pt), False)

   def miner_not_full_action(world, action, ticks):
      entity = action.entity
      entity_pt = MinerNotFull.get_position(entity)
      ore = find_nearest(world, entity_pt, entities.Ore)
      (tiles, found) = self.miner_to_ore(world, entity, ore)

      if found:
         entity = try_transform_miner(world, entity,
            try_transform_miner_not_full)

      schedule_action(world, entity,
         create_miner_action(entity, action.image_store),
         ticks + entities.get_rate(entity))
      return tiles

   def take_action(world, action, ticks):
      entities.remove_pending_action(action.entity, action)

      if isinstance(action, MinerNotFullAction):
         return self.miner_not_full_action(world, action, ticks)

      return []
```

And when I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 68, in <module>
    main(len(sys.argv) <= MIN_ARGS or sys.argv[INIT_ARG_IDX] != INIT_ARG_RANDOM)
  File "main.py", line 64, in main
    controller.activity_loop(view, world)
  File "/Users/KarenLee/CPE102/hw01/controller.py", line 50, in activity_loop
    handle_timer_event(world, view)
  File "/Users/KarenLee/CPE102/hw01/controller.py", line 27, in handle_timer_event
    rects = worldmodel.update_on_time(world, pygame.time.get_ticks())
  File "/Users/KarenLee/CPE102/hw01/worldmodel.py", line 78, in update_on_time
    tiles.extend(actions.take_action(world, next.item, ticks))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'take_action'
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: Full traceback please

Comment: Looks like the error is coming from somewhere else. When you made `take_action` a method (incorrectly, by the way), did you remember to change the places that call it?

Comment: Sure, actually, hang on, let me edit my code a bit.

Comment: The code posted here **will not** throw that exception. It is the code you used to try and call the method that throws it. Please show the full traceback and the relevant code.

Comment: The first argument to a method should be `self`.

Comment: Oh! That must be why, and could you explain to me why it's an incorrect method??

Comment: The missing `self` is another problem; it won't have caused the exception.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should show the relevant code, since there's so much. But if you could help me interpret the full traceback, that would be great. It's a little hard for me to understand exactly what the traceback is referring to.

Comment: The lines in the stack trace tell us *how you got to the exception*. The last few lines are especially crucial. It sounds as if you imported the module and confused the module with the contained class, but we cannot see this without seeing the lines of code that triggered the exception. The part of the code that is named in the last lines of the traceback would be helpful.

Comment: What is `actions` in that part of the code? The exception tells you it is a *module*, not an instance of your `MinerNotFullAction` class.

Comment: Do you have any files named `action` in your package? Since the error says `'module' object has no attribute 'take_action'`, I think the name of your file and name of object _may_ be clashing.

Comment: There is a file named, "actions.py" and there is a method that's called take_action. Does that help?

Comment: But the `actions` module used in your code does not have such a function. It is a different module than you expected, or the definition of the function definition isn't working. The class you posted has problems but is a red herring here.

Comment: Was `actions` meant to be bound to an instance of the `MinerNotFullAction` class instead? Please show us the code that defines `action` and the import line for the module `action`.

Comment: Specifically, what does the `worldmodel.py` file import, what does the `update_on_time` function in that file do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a file named `actions.py` in your package. When you do

```
actions.take_action(world, next.item, ticks)
```

It looks up `take_action()` in `actions.py` module and throws the error.

From the code it is clear that `take_action` is actually a method of `MinerNotFullAction`, thus the line `actions.take_action(world, next.item, ticks)` is supposed to call the method for *some object* `actions`. It is a naming conflict, hence the error

A solution would be to rename your `MinerNotFullAction` object (currently named `actions`) to something else

```
miner_action = MinerNotFullAction()
```

Then in your code instead of `actions.take_action` do `miner_action.take_action`.

**POSTSCRIPT**

Even if you remove this naming conflict there are some other problems (as people have already said in the comments), specifically your methods are missing `self` arguments.

Comment: @Karen Last line of the traceback

Comment: Just wondering, but could I rename it to this: "MinerNotFullAction.take_action..."?

Comment: @Karen `MinerNotFullAction` is your class and hence `MinerNotFullAction.take_action` is actually an _unbound_ method and won't work. I'd recommend you go through Python objects and classes